# How to add signed certificates to a bitcoin bip70 payment message? python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, bitcoin

References:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0070.mediawiki
https://github.com/aantonop/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/selected%20BIPs/bip-0070.mediawiki#paymentdetailspaymentrequest

```
message PaymentRequest {
    ##optional uint32 payment_details_version = 1 [default = 1]; # 'x509+sha256' in this case.
    ##optional string pki_type = 2 [default = "none"];
    optional bytes pki_data = 3;
    ##required bytes serialized_payment_details = 4;
    optional bytes signature = 5;
}
```

The ones with `##` at the front are not a problem, I've solved them already.

`optional bytes pki_data` wants a byte encoded version of 'x509+sha256' so...

```
x509_bytes = open('/path/to/x509.der', 'rb').read()
pki_data = hashib.sha256(x509_bytes)
```

Is the above correct?

Next `optional bytes signature`, 'digital signature over a hash of the protocol buffer serialized variation of the PaymentRequest message'

I'm not sure how to achieve this so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Finally I have...

```
message X509Certificates {
        repeated bytes certificate = 1;
    }
```

`repeated bytes certificate` 'Each certificate is a DER [ITU.X690.1994] PKIX certificate value. The certificate containing the public key of the entity that digitally signed the PaymentRequest MUST be the first certificate.'

I only have the one cert I got from the comodo root authority so I think I only need to supply the raw byte data of the cert to satisfy this one which already exists in the form of `x509_bytes` above, so...

```
repeated bytes certificate = x509_bytes
```

Am I close??

Also I notice that `repeated bytes certificate` comes after `optional bytes signature` but shouldn't I deal with that before `message PaymentRequest` so that I can serialise it into my http response somehow?

EDIT:

For what it's worth I'm aware that I need to import, instantiate and in some cases serialise these methods before sending them as a request/response but what I'm looking for are the methods on how to manipulate and supply the information required.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add PKI data to the PaymentRequest object:

```
pki_data = X509Certificates()
certificates = [your_cert_der_data, root_cert_der_data]
for cert in certificates:
    pki_data.certificate.append(cert)
request.pki_data = pki_data.SerializeToString()
```

To add a signature (with [pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/)):

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

# At this moment request object must contain serialized_payment_details, pki_type and pki_data
request.signature = ""  # Add empty signature
request_hash = SHA256.new(request.SerializeToString())
private_key = RSA.importKey(private_key_der_data)
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
request.signature = signer.sign(request_hash)
result = request.SerializeToString()
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I've basically mimicked your code exactly as shown above, just wondered if you could tell me...
Rather than adding each cert with a for loop I have already concatenated them into a single .der format file for nginx so does that mean I am ok to just add the bundle in one step?
The reason I ask is because the btc client is still reporting that the payment request is unverified :(

Comment: I fixed it by not trying to concatenate the the certificates and simply added them one at a time instead. Thanks very much for solving my problem :)